# Asus zenfone 8 Ringtones Replacement

Tags: applications

I have the Asus Zenfone 8 (about a month ago).
The factory ringtones have to go as I would like to obtain other ringtones.
Bottom line-is there way to transfer ringtones including notification-tones, from other phone i have (windows Microsoft Lumia 6) to the zenphone 8? Or if not exact or by copying each of its tones, there are other ringtones it looks like but I don't know the process in assembling like MP3 file(s). Which is why I'm posting question for possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Smartphone usually use common audio files in MP3, Ogg Vorbis or a similar format. Just copy the audio files to your new phone and configure them in Android settings as ring, notification or what else tone is supported.